# Delay a jquery function without timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen many stack or google answer, where to delay a function there is a suggestion for timer. But is there a way to delay a function with out using timer. Or other way is there a event where once a event for eg onclick or on blur is done check for the event end and call a function in a lazy manner without using timer.

Comment: How _blur is done_ identified ?

Comment: So you want to introduce a delay, but you don't want to use a timer and you don't want to use a listener.  How exactly do you want to to be delayed?

Comment: onblur you call a function. In that function you call another function but you need to delay the function without using timer

Comment: Take all the RAM out of your computer and se if that slows it down enough. No, you can't.

Comment: But can we delay a funciton without using timer is there any way ..?

Comment: Depend on the server speed timer function can affect the application. There by I wanted to know is there any alternative to delay a function without using timer

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You're literally asking "how can I DELAY without using DELAY"... Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @AndréDion I want to delay the function without using timer as depend on server it may affect the application. I have asked for an alternative There might be something.

Comment: @AndréDion It's an awkward question because it's the sort of thing you could potentially achieve in other languages (e.g. push something to a queue which then gets polled by another thread and executed. Depending on the speed of polling this will delay the start of the execution). Ultimately this is what the JavaScript engine is doing, it's just all that stuff is closed behind a door that we can't generally see and therefore you can't implement features like that yourself in JavaScript without the use of `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to delay execution of a function is to do so as a callback in response to something. I believe this pretty much always means you need to have a trigger in the native implementation, as JavaScript is single threaded and will run until it runs out of code to execute.

Typical things that trigger a function call from native code are

- Timers firing
- Events firing
- Async operations completing (eg. Http requests).

Out of these the timer is the only practical one to execute a function later without interactions being required by the user.

So **no**, not really I'd the short answer.

You can read more about the JavaScript Event Loop at the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

[image]